# How to get only the referenced objects in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I have two models:

```py
class ArticleCategory(models.Model):
    Category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Category_name

class Article(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    Content = tinymce_models.HTMLField(null=False, blank=False)
    Category = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleCategory,blank=False)
```

Assuming that the user will create some categories without necessarily linking them to any article, how do I get all the `ArticleCategory` objects that at least have one `Article` object linked to them?

Comment: Considering you will have a category for each article, do you need the category model?  You would just need to call all existing categories created under the article model. (may be I'm missing something)

Comment: Yeah. I want to list all the article categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reverse relation in filtering with `isnull` lookup:

```
ArticleCategory.objects.filter(articles__isnull=False).distinct()
```

But first, add `related_name` to the proper field:

```
Category = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleCategory, blank=False, related_name="articles")
```

By the way, don't name fields in CamelCase style, save it for class names.

Comment: It works, but it returns multiple entries for each record unless I add  `.distinct()` at the end of the filter query.

Comment: Yes, forgot about that. Accepted the edit in the answer.